# how to run ubuntu command with root permission using phpseclib

Tags: php, sudo, phpseclib

I use phpseclib to calling ssh command from php.

```
$ip = 'ip_address';
$login = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$ssh = new SSH2($ip);
$ssh->login($login, $password);
```

In example below everything is ok (because I dont need permissions):

```
$command = 'ifconfig';
$result = $ssh->exec($command); // result = 'eth0 ..., eth1 etc.'
```

Problem occurs in the next example:

```
$command = 'ip addr flush dev eth1';
$result = $ssh->exec($command); // result = 'Failed to send flush request: Operation not permitted'
```

I tried to log in with sudo su:

```
$result = $ssh->read('$'); // result = '..... user@hostname:~$'
$result = $ssh->write("sudo su\n"); //result = true
$result = $ssh->read(':');  // result = 'sudo su\n [sudo] password for user:'
$result = $ssh->write($password."\n"); // result = true
$result = $ssh->read('#'); //result = 'root@hostname:/home/user#
```

It seems that everything is okay (I'm on root), but:

```
$command = 'ip addr flush dev eth1';
$result = $ssh->exec($command);  // result = 'Failed to send flush request: Operation not permitted'
```

Where is a problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try adding yourself in the sudoers file, and then just type sudo  followed by the command (you dont need insert password)

Comment: `su` is already a suid binary. there's no need to run it `sudo`, because it ALWAYS runs as root.

Comment: i tried something like this in terminal: `adduser user sudo` and the result is:
`The user 'user' is already a member of 'sudo'`. Next I used only `su` in terminal and result is: `Password: 
su: Authentication failure`

Comment: it's ubuntu version 16.04 LTS, now i have root password (`sudo passwd root`) and will try to use phpseclib with su only

Comment: it's not working as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the following code from http://mrbluecoat.blogspot.com/2014/03/running-sudo-commands-with-phpseclib.html:

```
$ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
$ssh->write("sudo YOUR COMMAND HERE\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(10);
$output = $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]|.*[pP]assword.*/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
if (preg_match('/.*[pP]assword.*/', $output)) {
    $ssh->write($sudo_password."\n");
    $ssh->read('/.*@.*[$|#]/', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
}
```

and it works!

Comment: Doing `$ssh->setTimeout(10)` shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need add httpd process (apache,php) to root user group.That the subsidiary process can run with root perm.